# Python unable to open a .h5 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to open a HDF5 file in order to read it with python, so that I can do more things with it later. There is an error when I run the program to read the file. The program is below:

```
import h5py    # HDF5 support
import numpy

fileName = "C:/.../file.h5"
f = h5py.File(fileName,  "r")
for item in f.attrs.keys():
    print item + ":", f.attrs[item]
mr = f['/entry/mr_scan/mr']
i00 = f['/entry/mr_scan/I00']
print "%s\t%s\t%s" % ("#", "mr", "I00")
for i in range(len(mr)):
    print "%d\t%g\t%d" % (i, mr[i], i00[i])
f.close()
```

If I run the program I end up seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "TestHD5.py", line 8, in <module>
    mr = f['/entry/mr_scan/mr']
 File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2587)
 File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2546)
 File "C:\programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 166, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
 File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2587)
 File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2546)
 File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open (C:\aroot\work\h5py\h5o.c:3417)
KeyError: 'Unable to open object (Component not found)'
```

Am I just missing some modules to read the file, or is this something else. It will open the .h5 file if I use an h5 file veiwer program. Thank you

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or output. Paste the code & output directly, so it's much easier to work with.

Comment: Sorry I hope this makes it better @RushyPanchal

Comment: Sorry I hope this makes it better @RadLexus

Comment: Try putting and `r` in front of your file name;  `r"C:\User`.

Comment: Avoid backslashes in paths like the plague. Python will happily convert forward-slashes (`/`) to backslashes on Windows for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string:

```
path = "C:\Users\312001\m2020\data\20170104_145626\doPoint_20170104_150016\dataset_XMIT    data_20170104_150020.h5"
```

is full of broken/illegal [escapes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (thankfully they will be turned into SyntaxErrors, though you are using Python 2), and some that actually *do* work, so Python thinks `path` is really equal to: `'C:\\Users\xca001\\m2020\\data\x8170104_145626\\doPoint_20170104_150016\\dataset_XMIT    data_20170104_150020.h5'` (note those `\x##`'s).

Your options:

1. Use a [*raw* string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) by prefixing the string literal with `r`
2. Don't use backslashes for paths. Python will convert forward slashes to backslashes for Windows paths.
3. Double-backslash.

Comment: Thanks that got rid UnicodeDecodeError and some of the other lines that the terminal was displaying. Ill edit it so that you can see what it shows now. I am still unable to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @NickT posted fixed the orginal problem I had. The problem that is shown in the new version is due to the hd5 folder names in the hd5 file not matching the folder names that the code provided.