# ’Unable to open object (component not found)'

Tags: python, c++, h5py

I am trying to assign the output of test.sample(state) to a file named test_out.h5 and in particular, to create a new group named sample_. However, even though it compiles and runs properly (as part of a much bigger code which cannot reduced to a minimal working example), when I try to open the file I get ’Unable to open object (component not found)’. I am aware of the existence of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473368/h5py-randomly-unable-to-open-object-component-not-found) post, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474634/python-unable-to-open-a-h5-file), which I didn't find helpful.

```
   size_t num=5;

   {
   std::string test_out = "test_out.h5";
   H5::H5File f(test_out, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

   for (size_t m = 0; m < num; m++){
      string name=std::to_string(m);
      H5::Group grp = f.createGroup("sample_"+name);
      test.sample(state);
      state.saveState(grp);}
    H5close();
    }
```

I am trying to open the file in Python3 as follows:

```
     f4=h5py.File('<my_dir>/test_out.h5', 'r')
     print(list(f4.keys()))
```

and it fails right there.

If anyone could point out the mistake I would be grateful. Please, bare in mind that I should not change any of the packages used in the C++ code.

**Update:** The same routine opened the file on another computer, so I am still trying to figure out what is suddenly wrong with my h5py installation.

Comment: Please *do not* repeat the tags in the question title needlessly.

Comment: First thing to determine: is the problem your h5py installation or the file (test_out.h5). File validity tests: 1) run h5dump test_out.h5, 2) open test_out.h5 with the HDFViewer utility.

Comment: Just opened the file on another computer, so the problem is my h5py installation. It was working just fine previously and I uninstalled and re-installed but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open the file by changing the version of h5py. Atm, I cannot provide explanation as to why running on the terminal with the latest version of h5py suddenly presented problems, but jupyter notebook also works with the previous h5py installation.